# Crash reports no longer include stack trace?

Tags: google-play-console, crash-reports

In my Play Console > Android Vitals > Crashes and ANRs I used to be able to access a stack trace for each reported crash.

But now all I see is this:

[image]

How do I get back the stack traces?